# How to skip a specific position within a for each loop in c sharp?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

```
List<string> liste = new List<String> 
        {
            "A","B","C","D"
        };

        foreach (var item in liste)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(liste[i].ToString());
        }
```

How do i skip a specific position in a foreach loop? I do not want to evaluate any values, but just skip the position x.

It has to be a specific position. One could choose position 0 or maybe position 7.

Comment: What is a problem with your example? if (i==0) continue seems right.

Comment: There is no problem, but i have a bunch of foreach loops and i wondered if there is any command to do it like in normal for loop. Just imagine you have on all your Lists at position 4 some value, that you want to skip

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is very easy to skip the first item in the list:

```
foreach(var item in list.Skip(1))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

If you want to skip any other element at index `n`, you could write this:

```
foreach(var item in list.Where((a,b) => b != n))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

In this example I use a lambda expression that takes two arguments: `a` and `b`. Argument `a` is the item itself, while argument `b` is the index of the item.

The relevant pages on MSDN that describe these extension methods are:

- [IEnumerable.Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)
- [IEnumerable.Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)

You could even write your own extension method that allows you to skip an element in a list:

```
public static class MyEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int index)
    {
        var i = 0;

        foreach(var item in list) 
        {
            if(i != index)
                yield return item;

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to write something like this to skip an item:

```
foreach(var item in list.SkipAt(2))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: i know about skip, but how do u skip the specific position 4? 1,2,3 =ok, 4= skip, 5,6..=ok.

Comment: +1 Much better than my answer. I didn't know you could do that with `Where`.

Comment: @Gero : I modified my answer to cover the generic case.

Answer (score 1):

A `foreach` loop iterates over a collection that implements `IEnumerable`. The enumerator exposes the current item and a method to move onto the next item - it has no concept of an index.

You could always do:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in liste) {
  if (i++ == skip) continue;
  Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

But this seems unnecessarily contrived. If you need an index, go with a `for` loop.

The other option is to remove the undesired item from the `List` before iterating:

```
foreach (var item in liste.Take(n-1).Union(liste.Skip(n))) {
  Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love list's .ForEach, here's my take using @Elian's .SkipAt(n) and .ForEach:

```cs
var list = new List<String> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
list = list.SkipAt(1).ToList();
list.ForEach(Debug.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the enhanced version of the Where extension method that allows you to filter on item and index.

Check the reference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Verbatim list");
            List<string> list = new List<String> { "A","B","C","D" };

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Filtered list");
            int itemToSkip = 2;
            foreach (var item in list.Where((item, index) => index != itemToSkip))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the following output.

```
Verbatim list
A
B
C
D
Filtered list
A
B
D
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip a  position inside the foreach loop, one option is that you can skip the action inside the foreach loop by using an if statement, like

```
foreach(var item in liste)
{
    if (item != 'X')
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But i am waiting for better solutions

Comment: dont evaluate the item ^^, but check somehow for actual position of the foreach in the list.