# For I loop in C# ignore a value of I

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am storing a token in a 2D array grid, this token can move one position at a time.
When the token moves I check each position using a for loop like the one below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    // Do things
}
```

Because the tokens current position will always be 4 I have included an if statement to avoid checking the tokens current position

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(i != 4){
        // Do things////
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force the loop to automatically skip i = 4 inside the declarations or is this the best way to ignore it.

Comment: There's no way of automatically skipping an index in a for loop, you've got the best solution already.

Comment: I would prefer to use: `if (i == 4) continue` since it prevents code nesting

Comment: Could be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942467/3888657

Comment: @TomasChabada I think that you may have the best suggestion. If you make it as an answer I will accept it for you.

Comment: @Parzavil Ok, I posted it, thank you

Comment: you could receive the same behaviour with an switch(i), case 4:break and default: DoThings. Readability is okay, in your case, avoidiong more than one index can blow up your logic, but just wanted to throw another possibility at this topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is completely fine, just one suggestion: I would use

```
if (i == 4) continue;
```

to prevent code nesting

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is the best solution but if you really want to avoid this `if` statement you can always use `foreach`:

```cs
var iterList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
foreach (int element in iterList)
{
    // use element
}
```

But this does not seem to be efficient and memory friendly.

Comment: While this might work, it's likely going to be slower and definitely less readable.

Comment: If you go this path, I'd prefer the more readable `var iterList = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Except(new[] { 4 });`. In your example, it's really hard to see that `4` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
foreach (int item in numbers.Where((number, index) => index != 4))
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```